# How to filter from an array of objects using multiple filter words and multiple keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array of objects and an array of filters. Each object in the array has an id and an array of "tasks." I would like to filter from the array of tasks within each object using only the "assignedTo" and "priority" keys. The array of filters represents what should be removed.

Array of objects:

```
const TASKS = [
{
 id: "To Do",
 tasks: [
     {
         name: 'Get to work',
         created: 'July 7, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Cody',
         description: 'I have to get to work',
         attachment: "",
         priority: 'red'
      },
      {
         name: 'Pick up groceries',
         created: 'July 8, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Bob',
         description: 'Go to grocery store',
         attachment: "",
         priority: 'limegreen'
      },
      {
         name: 'Go home',
         created: 'July 9, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Cody',
         description: 'Lets go back home',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'red'
      },
      {
         name: 'Fall asleep',
         created: 'July 9, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Tom',
         description: 'Time for bed',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'gold'
      },
    ],
  },
{    
 id: "Done",
 tasks: [
      {
         name: 'Get up', 
         created: 'July 7, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Cody',
         description: 'Time to start the day',
         attachment: "1",
         priority: 'red'
      },
      {
         name: 'Brush teeth',
         created: 'July 8, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Bob',
         description: 'Brush',
         attachment: "",
         priority: 'limegreen'
      },
      {
         name: 'Check e-mail',
         created: 'July 11, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Jake',
         description: 'Anyhting new?',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'red'
      },
      {
         name: 'Walk dog',
         created: 'July 12, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Bob',
         description: 'He needs to go out',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'gold'
      },
    ],
  },
{
 id: "In Progress",
 tasks: [
      {
         name: 'Wash Clothes',
         created: 'July 8, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Bob',
         description: 'Brush',
         attachment: "",
         priority: 'limegreen'
      },
      {
         name: 'Go to doctors',
         created: 'July 10, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Jake',
         description: 'Anyhting new?',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'red'
      },
      {
         name: 'Get gasoline',
         created: 'July 9, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Jonathan',
         description: 'He needs to go out',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'gold'
      },
    ],
  }
];
```

Example of an array of filters:

```
filters: ["limegreen","red","Tom"];
```

Using this array of filters the object array should look like:

```
filteredTasks = [
{
 id: "To Do",
 tasks: [
     
    ],
  },
{    
 id: "Done",
 tasks: [
      {
         name: 'Walk dog',
         created: 'July 12, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Bob',
         description: 'He needs to go out',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'gold'
      },
    ],
  },
{
 id: "In Progress",
 tasks: [
      {
         name: 'Get gasoline',
         created: 'July 9, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Jonathan',
         description: 'He needs to go out',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'gold'
      },
    ],
  }
];
```

Any subsequent array of filters will only be used on the original object array (TASKS) so I need to preserve the original list as well. If the array of filters is empty, the original object array (TASKS) should be returned.

Comment: @dippas I have tried on my own but none of my attempts got me the desired results. I see no reason to include my incorrect functions and possibly risk confusing helpful commenters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with `filter` and `includes`

```js
const tasks = [
{
 id: "To Do",
 tasks: [
     {
         name: 'Get to work',
         created: 'July 7, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Cody',
         description: 'I have to get to work',
         attachment: "",
         priority: 'red'
      },
      {
         name: 'Pick up groceries',
         created: 'July 8, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Bob',
         description: 'Go to grocery store',
         attachment: "",
         priority: 'limegreen'
      },
      {
         name: 'Go home',
         created: 'July 9, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Cody',
         description: 'Lets go back home',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'red'
      },
      {
         name: 'Fall asleep',
         created: 'July 9, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Tom',
         description: 'Time for bed',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'gold'
      },
    ],
  },
{    
 id: "Done",
 tasks: [
      {
         name: 'Get up', 
         created: 'July 7, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Cody',
         description: 'Time to start the day',
         attachment: "1",
         priority: 'red'
      },
      {
         name: 'Brush teeth',
         created: 'July 8, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Bob',
         description: 'Brush',
         attachment: "",
         priority: 'limegreen'
      },
      {
         name: 'Check e-mail',
         created: 'July 11, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Jake',
         description: 'Anyhting new?',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'red'
      },
      {
         name: 'Walk dog',
         created: 'July 12, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Bob',
         description: 'He needs to go out',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'gold'
      },
    ],
  },
{
 id: "In Progress",
 tasks: [
      {
         name: 'Wash Clothes',
         created: 'July 8, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Bob',
         description: 'Brush',
         attachment: "",
         priority: 'limegreen'
      },
      {
         name: 'Go to doctors',
         created: 'July 10, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Jake',
         description: 'Anyhting new?',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'red'
      },
      {
         name: 'Get gasoline',
         created: 'July 9, 2022',
         assignedTo: 'Jonathan',
         description: 'He needs to go out',
         attachment: "" ,
         priority: 'gold'
      },
    ],
  }
];

const filters = ["limegreen","red","Tom"];


const result = tasks.map(tasksGroup => {
  tasksGroup.tasks = [...tasksGroup.tasks].filter(task => {
    return !(filters.includes(task.priority) || filters.includes(task.assignedTo))
  })
  return tasksGroup
})

console.log(result)
```